# Apply interest rate recursively in Excel table

Tags: excel

I have a table in an Excel workbook that I'm using to manage a budget for various accounts. Every month I want the budget to increase by some small percentage. I've built a simplistic demo of that I need at [Calculate monthly budget increase](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjcmU60daA9VqsZz1a3_0zemuNLtOg)

Here's a screenshot of it:
[image]

I basically need a formula that increases the budget every month, per account, by adding a given percentage (in cell B1) to the previous month. Note, not interested in using VBA. This has to be done with a formula.

Hope that makes sense. Suspect I haven't explained myself very well.

Answer (score 1):

Using an Excel Table for this is an unfortunate decision, because in a table you'd typically have the same formula applied to the whole column. In your case it looks as if that will not be the case, since some rows have values manually entered and you seem to want the empty cells to contain formulas.

You can use this formula starting in cell F3

```
=F2+(F2*$B$1)
```

Copy and paste to all empty cells in the column.